# Keeping track of currentTimeMillis

Tags: java, stopwatch

I need to create an object that will stop execution for a certain amount of time using its own class methods. How do I have a program keep track of passing time and execute a function when a specified amount of time has passed.

I imagine .......

```
long pause; //a variable storing pause length in milliseconds.............
long currentTime; // which store the time of execution of the pause ,.............
```

and when another variable tracking time has the same value as currentTime + pause, the next line of code is executed.  Is it possible to make a variable that for a short period changes every millisecond as time passes?

Comment: i can't use any threads :\ for the assignment

Comment: @FredV Techniqually, you already are, your code is executing in thread already, you don't have to do anything...

Comment: yeah yeah yeah ! it not mentioned explicitly in the restrictions :D!

Comment: `Thread.sleep()` is a static method.  It doesn't create any threads, it makes the *current* thread (the one that calls it) sleep.  Every Java program starts with one thread that runs the `main()` method; when people talk about "using threads" they mean creating *additional* ones besides that initial one.

Comment: "Do not use the Java Thread class but consider how you can stall a program using simple tech- niques."

Comment: @FredV I don't like you're lecturer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a simple solution, you could just use [`Thread#sleep`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29)

```
public void waitForExecution(long pause) throws InterruptedException { 
    // Perform some actions...
    Thread.sleep(pause);
    // Perform next set of actions
}
```

With a timer...

```
public class TimerTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Timer timer = new Timer("Happy", false);
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Hello, I'm from the future!");
            }
        }, 5000);

        System.out.println("Hello, I'm from the present");
    }
}
```

And with a loop

```
long startAt = System.currentTimeMillis();
long pause = 5000;
System.out.println(DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date()));
while ((startAt + pause) > System.currentTimeMillis()) {
    // Waiting...
}
System.out.println(DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date()));
```

Note, this is more expensive then the other two solutions as the loop continues to consume CPU cycles, where as the `Thread#sleep` and `Timer` use a internal scheduling mechanism that allows the threads to idle (and not consume cycles)

Comment: eugh, i know he wants the for loop. i will test n fiddle, thank you so much for the direction @MadProgrammer :)

Comment: You could be nice in the `while` loop and call `Thread#yield`, which will at least give other threads in the system a chance to run, but that might overkill for what you're trying to achieve